# NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: android, xml, notifications

I send in the constructor of the class that extends nothing **context**

```
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setWhen(when)
                .setTicker(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR);
```

and then I send some datas through RemoteViews and on the end

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Menu_Activity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layoutNotification, contentIntent);
myNotification.setContent(remoteView);

myNotification.setOngoing(false);
myNotification.setAutoCancel(false);

myNotification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
myNotification.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

myNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification.build());
```

but I need to set this notification, that it will be not possible to delete by swipe it to the side. Now everytimes I can delete it by swiping. How to disable that?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to set ongoing to `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notification builder has a method setOngoing. Set that to true to make the notification an ongoing notification that can't be dismissed by the user.

> Set whether this is an "ongoing" notification. Ongoing notifications
>   cannot be dismissed by the user, so your application or service must
>   take care of canceling them. They are typically used to indicate a
>   background task that the user is actively engaged with (e.g., playing
>   music) or is pending in some way and therefore occupying the device
>   (e.g., a file download, sync operation, active network connection).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setOngoing(true) only. Remove setAutoCancel(false) line.

Using of setOngoing() and setAutoCancel() methods together don`t work for me (notification is not showed).